# D3,js error "d.parent.data is undefined" in mbostock/raw/910126/ sunburst chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I have downloaded the code from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/910126/ and I believe that I have also downloaded the correct json file (based on flare.json). However, when I run the script the sunburst chart is completely black and apparently due to error "d.parent.data is undefined" in the color function:

```
.attr("fill", function(d) { 
   return color(
      (d.children ? d : d.parent).data.key); 
      })
```

Other than changing the json file the code matches the example code. The only other difference is that I am running the code as a Drupal node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. I modded the code a bit to get to colors and text - http://jsfiddle.net/LxGv2/

Two changes:

1) for color :

```
.attr("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.value);;
})
```

2) for text:

```
text(function (d) {
    return d.key;
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! It works. Do you have any idea why the example did not? It worked properly when I viewed it.